# How to convert an object into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

I have array of object and I want to change into array an remove object.

My object is like:

`[{ABC: "ELEMENT1", MAX: 2, MIN: "Yes"}, {ABC: "ELEMENT2", MAX: 1, MIN: "Yes"}]`

and I want result like array with index:

`[{"ELEMENT1",2,"Yes"},{"ELEMENT2",2,"Yes}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over [**`Object.keys(obj)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

*The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.*

*The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.*

```js
var ip = {
  STU: "Study1",
  SUB: 2,
  EXL: "Yes"
};
var op = Object.keys(ip).map(function(key) {
  return ip[key];
});
console.log(op);
```

**To iterate `Array-of-Objects`**

```js
var ip = [{
  STU: "Study1",
  SUB: 2,
  EXL: "Yes"
}, {
  STU: "Study2",
  SUB: 4,
  EXL: "No"
}];
var op = ip.map(function(item) {
  return Object.keys(item).map(function(key) {
    return item[key];
  });
});

console.log(op);
```

Comment: @user6474292 – What do you mean by `many` ? Do you mean `Nested-object` ?

Comment: I have array of objects and each object I want to change its value to array.

Comment: @user6474292, You will have to iterate that `array`.. Do update your question to understand your query better..

Answer (score 5):

That would be:

```
var array = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
```

However, *order is not guaranteed* for `Object.keys` as it works like a `for-in` loop, whose order of traversal is arbitrary. You may not get `["Study1",2,"Yes"]` in that exact order. If you want to guarantee order, you must use an array containing the order of the keys and extract them from your object in that order.

```
var keyArray = ['STU', 'SUB', 'EXL'];
var array = keyArray.map(key => obj[key]);
```